# How to change/alter the data type of a column from a table which has a custom data type in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, custom-data-type, alter-column

I have a custom datatype as below.

```
CREATE TYPE myschema.test AS (
        id text,
        event text,
        severity text,
        status text,
        value text,
        text text,
        type text,
        update_time timestamp without time zone
    );
```

I am using this datatype in one of the tables. Now I want to change the schema of this data type and create it as myschema1.Test and alter the column of the table with new data type created in myschema1. But I am getting an error as below even if both the data types are having the same structure.

```
alter table if exists myschema1.table 
   alter column testcolumn type myschema1.test;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  column "testcolumn" cannot be cast automatically to type myschema1.test
> HINT:  You might need to specify "USING testcolumn::myschema1.test".
> ```

When I tried using cast operator as per the hint facing the below error.

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot cast type myschema.test[] to myschema1.test
> LINE 1: ...test type myschema1.test using testcolumn::myschema1...
> ```

How to handle this one?

Comment: You will need to show the table definition where you use and are trying to alter the type. At a guess you have declared the column to be an array of `myschema.test`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . This is my table structure. CREATE TABLE myschema1.table (
    id text NOT NULL,
    resource text NOT NULL,
    testcolumn myschema.test
);

Comment: Your schema is already broken. Don't use composite types in table definitions and don't use arrays.

Comment: 1) The table definition you show is not for the one you are doing the type change on. That table has `testcolumn` defined as an array `myschema.test[]`. 2) My testing indicated you cannot `CAST` from one composite type to another so the `USING` is not going to work in any case. 3) See @LaurenzAlbe's comment an rethink your design.